# I am developing VS Code extension and I need to capture the call stack records and log the result

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

I am writing a simple VS Code extension that suppose to just log the call stack in the console at specific point while debugging a code.

I was able to write a code to retrieve the current session of debugging, the break points and things like this, but I failed to find any property or method to allow me retrieve the call stack records.

This is the code I wrote:

```
export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    

    console.log('Congratulations, your extension "sampleextension1" is now active!');


    let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('sampleextension1.hello', () => {
        vscode.window.showInformationMessage('Hello World from sampleextension1!');
        vscode.commands.executeCommand('editor.action.addCommentLine');

        
         vscode.debug.onDidStartDebugSession(x => {
        });

        vscode.debug.onDidChangeActiveDebugSession(c => {
            var b = vscode.debug.breakpoints[0];
            
        });

        
    });

    context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
}
```

As you see in the code, there is an event handler for `onDidChangeActiveDebugSession` which enables me to capture the session of the debugging but no chance to find how to capture the stack trace.

I went through the documentation but it's not helpful though.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve what I want by sending a CutomRequest to the debugging session to retrieve the stack frames.

More information could be found in the DAP page [here](https://microsoft.github.io/debug-adapter-protocol/)

The code is as shown below:

```
    x.customRequest('stackTrace', { threadId: 1 }).then(reply => {
                const frameId = reply.stackFrames[0].id; 
            }, error => {
                vscode.window.showInformationMessage(`error: ${error.message}`);
            });
```

or more efficient is to register tracker as shown below:

```
        vscode.debug.registerDebugAdapterTrackerFactory('*', {
            createDebugAdapterTracker(session: vscode.DebugSession) {
              return {
                onWillReceiveMessage: m => console.log(`> ${JSON.stringify(m, undefined, 2)}`),
                onDidSendMessage: m => console.log(`< ${JSON.stringify(m, undefined, 2)}`)
              };
            }
          });
```

The full example is shown here:

```
export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    

    console.log('Congratulations, your extension "sampleextension1" is now active!');


    let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('sampleextension1.hello', () => {
        vscode.window.showInformationMessage('Hello World from sampleextension1!');
        vscode.commands.executeCommand('editor.action.addCommentLine');

         vscode.debug.onDidStartDebugSession(x => {
            
            // x.customRequest("evaluate", {
            //     "expression": "Math.sqrt(10)"
            // }).then(reply => {
            //     vscode.window.showInformationMessage(`result: ${reply.result}`);
            // }, error => {
            //     vscode.window.showInformationMessage(`error: ${error.message}`);
            // });

            x.customRequest('stackTrace', { threadId: 1 }).then(reply => {
                const frameId = reply.stackFrames[0].id; 
            }, error => {
                vscode.window.showInformationMessage(`error: ${error.message}`);
            });

        });

        vscode.debug.onDidChangeActiveDebugSession(c => {
            var b = vscode.debug.breakpoints[0];
        });

        vscode.debug.registerDebugAdapterTrackerFactory('*', {
            createDebugAdapterTracker(session: vscode.DebugSession) {
              return {
                onWillReceiveMessage: m => console.log(`> ${JSON.stringify(m, undefined, 2)}`),
                onDidSendMessage: m => console.log(`< ${JSON.stringify(m, undefined, 2)}`)
              };
            }
          });

        
    });
```

Steps to run:

1. F5 to run the Extension Dev Environment.
2. Ctl+Shift+P then write your cmd, in my case it was Hello
3. Then F5 to start the debugging in the Dev Environment then you will be able to see the result.

Hope it helps